# New BLANK Project Android Studio ERROR: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: android, android-studio

I had a project that was running perfectly fine when suddenly this error started popping up "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect"

In a NEW project with no activity, when I build I still get 
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Things I have tried: 
Invalidate +restart, complete reinstallation (deleted .gradle and .Android3.1 etc). If it was an error with my code I could understand, but it happenening for a Blank new project is just messing with me.

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:50)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Could not normalize path for file 'D:\HalflNHalf\app\D:Android\.android\debug.keystore'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.FileNormaliser.normalise(FileNormaliser.java:90)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileResolver.resolve(AbstractFileResolver.java:88)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileResolver.resolve(AbstractFileResolver.java:68)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskInputs.toFile(DefaultTaskInputs.java:395)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskInputs.access$500(DefaultTaskInputs.java:48)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskInputs$6.validate(DefaultTaskInputs.java:355)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.TaskPropertyInfo$3.validate(TaskPropertyInfo.java:112)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskPropertyValue.validate(TaskPropertyValue.java:38)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskInputFilePropertySpec.validate(DefaultTaskInputFilePropertySpec.java:124)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskInputs.validate(DefaultTaskInputs.java:171)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:47)
... 27 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize(WinNTFileSystem.java:428)
at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:618)
at java.io.File.getCanonicalFile(File.java:643)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.FileNormaliser.normalise(FileNormaliser.java:54)
... 37 more
```

The project is completely empty and has just been generated by Android Studio. I have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and welcome to SO.
In the stacktrace, i read the following

> Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Could not normalize
>   path for file 'D:\HalflNHalf\app\D:Android.android\debug.keystore'

Check your signing configuration, maybe there is a mistake

Comment: Thank you SOO MUCH!, I didn't realize but it was pointing to the wrong directory . . .I'm still baffled as to how that changed, but it apparently did.